# Write data to GridView with json api (C# UWP)

Tags: c#, .net

In C # UWP I would like to display the data from the Zomato API via Gridview, but when I run the following code there is no result. In the meantime, when I run the API in the browser, the json code works. Please help me. Thank you!

XAML code here:

```
<PivotItem Header="Restoranlar">
    <Grid SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged" Background="{ThemeResource SystemBaseLowColor}">
    <GridView x:Name="itemGridView">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Restaurant">
            <Grid>
                <Image x:Name="menu" Source="{x:Bind photos_url}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,-25,0,0" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="name" Text="{x:Bind name}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock x:Name="ID" Text="{x:Bind url}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontSize="17" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
    </Grid>
</PivotItem>
```

C# code here:

```
        private async void GetRestaurants()
        {
            try
            {
                string strBingImageURL = string.Format("https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?apikey=" + APIKEY +"&count=10&lat=" + LatitudeF + "&lon=" + LongitudeF + "&category=restaurants&sort=real_distance&order=asc");
                string jsonText = "";

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(strBingImageURL));
                jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                JsonArray jsonData1 = JsonArray.Parse(jsonText);

                foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonData1)
                {
                    if (jsonData1.Count > 0)
                    {
                        JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();

                        string zname = groupObject["name"].GetString();
                        string zphotos = groupObject["photos_url"].GetString();
                        string zurl = groupObject["url"].GetString();

                        Restaurant file = new Restaurant();
                        file.name = zname;
                        file.url = zurl;
                        file.photos_url = zphotos;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //DoNothing
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                //Catch Here
            }
        }
```

Restaurant class here:

```
    public class Restaurant
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string photos_url { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I can't see from your code where you are storing the Restaurant objects, are they in an `ObservableCollection` or `List` of some sort?

If that is the case you are missing your `ItemsSource` property on the `GridView`, this would explain why you see nothing.

Comment: (https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?apikey=820b607ebfd6729fd1e255105f3bdc1a&count=10&lat=40.984715&lon=27.576684&category=cafe&sort=real_distance&order=asc)  Json file of the full version is available at this link. I have nothing but these codes. I want to print some of the data in the JSON file as a Binding to the Gridview. Could you tell me what to write to the Gridview ItemsSource? Thank you for help.

Comment: any luck with the answer I provided?

Comment: Ohh I'm so sorry I couldn't write an answer, I was not interested in my code several days because of New Year. I will try this evening or tomorrow. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Any luck with the answer provided? (If so could you please consider selecting it as the correct answer, if not I'm happy to provide further assistance)

Comment: I'm sorry to write late. I tried but it didn't work. Can you explain how to get data with JSON (UWP)? Unfortunately, the resources I searched did not work.

Comment: I've been able to recreate your issue, the C# code here fails with an exception. You aren't actually deserialising the JSON. A better explanation can be found in this answer - [parsing json in uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36516146/parsing-json-in-uwp). I've been able to get a GridView to load your JSON, I'll update my answer with a link to my Github profile when I get my test app uploaded.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Yes, I am really having trouble with JSON and I am a bit stranger to JSON even if it is not in C #. I can actually get Bing daily images with json, but here is what I want to be able to list the json data in the gridview or listview. If possible with the Bind method.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been sick. I've edited my answer to include the relevant info about deserializing the JSON. Also included a link to my full sample app I created on Github. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this soon and I will share the result with you. Thank you so much for helping me so much. By the way, I hope you get better soon. It is necessary to pay attention to the health in winter. Lemon tea and sleep will be good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your `GetRestaurants` method is in the code-behind of your View or in whatever you have as the DataContext for the View.

You'll need to add a public property of type `List<Restaurant>` or `ObservableCollection<Restaurant>`. Like so:

`ObservableCollection<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }`

Then in your `foreach` your new `Restaurant` object `file` to this `List` or `ObservableCollection`. I would recommend using an `ObservableCollection`.

Finally in your View, all you need to do is add the `Restaurants` property as the `GridView`'s `ItemsSource`. Like so:

`<GridView x:Name="itemGridView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Restaurants}">`

-Edit-

Where you are also going wrong is with the JSON deserialization. You aren't actually deserializing it in your code. You need to actually deserialize it into the objects it expects a better explanation and example of JSON deserialization can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36516146/parsing-json-in-uwp) on StackOverflow (see below for a snippet of what I've implemented to make your code work)

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(zomatoURL));
jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonText);
```

To see a full working sample of the Zomato API and some MVVM techniques see my sample [here](https://github.com/JSmyth886/UWP-Samples/tree/master/UWP-Samples/UWP-Samples).